# No logro relacionar un archivo CSS con uno HTML

Tags: html, css, style

Lo dicho, lo he hecho literal como el curso del youtuber HolaMundo y nada, no encuentro el error por ningún lado. En la consola de la página esta todo perfecto, así que el archivo css se carga bien. Adjunto capturas de código.

[image: codigo HTML]

[image: ambos archivos en la misma carpeta]
[image: código CSS]
[image: como se ve la página que no actualiza el color]

Comment: Tus comillas de link se ven bastante raras. Nota que no se ven igual que las de `src`. Intenta usar comillas simples `'  '` o dobles `" "`

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez era eso, muchísimas gracias hace un rato largo que estaba

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez marca la respuesta correcta y solución para que la pregunta no quede pendiente, saludos.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez y como hago eso?

Comment: Creo que  @Thanatos9516 se confundió. No puedes seleccionar ninguna respuesta porque no hay ninguna respuesta a tu pregunta. Te respondí por comentarios porque tu problema era simplemente un typo. La selección de respuestas se hace cuando alguien agrega una respuesta a tu pregunta.